# 301 redirect from webforms application to asp.net mvc 3 application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing, http-status-code-301

I want to do 301 redirect from the old asp.net webforms website hosted in IIS6 to the asp.net mvc 3 application hosted in same server.Following are the urls that i would like to redirect to the new urls.

http://oldsite.com/blog/888-miso-collapsible-origami-tables.aspx => www.somesite.com/postdetails/miso-collapsible-origami-tables

http://oldsite.com/blog.aspx?tag=art => www.somesite.com/Blog/TagPosts?tag=art&tagPostType=1

http://oldsite.com/blog.aspx?month=2012-3&p=2 =>www.somesite.com

How do i set up the matching route for the above to the  new site and make a 301 redirect.I don't know how to match the url with query string to my asp.net mvc 3 webapplication.What would be the route like be in my new mvc application and do i need to make changes in the web.config of my new application?

Thanks in advance,
S.

Comment: i will if i get the response for this for sure.